# From where to Get recorded call's audio file in Linphone iOS SDK

Tags: ios, swift, voip, linphone, linphone-sdk

Used following code to start recording

```
linphone_call_start_recording(call);
```

Used following code to stop recording:

```
linphone_call_stop_recording(call);
```

I am not getting any audio file stored in app local directory, Any idea where it can be located?
Can any one please suggest? It can help me a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recording audio file path has been defined with recordingFilePathFromCall function in LinphoneManager.m file